# Программный клик мышью в компоненте TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi

Можно ли сделать программный клик по определённым координатам(относительно компонента TWebBrowser) в компоненте TWebBrowser? Как это осуществить? (Почти всегда программа будет свёрнута в трей)
Заранее благодарю за ответ

Comment: всё таки клик по компоненту или содержимому страницы, загруженной в TWebBrowser?

Comment: По содержимому

Answer (score 1):

Ну по содержимому я не знаю, как кликать, но по компоненту так:

```
var pole: Variant;
pole:=WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getElementByid('Id');
pole.Click;
```

Может getElementByid можно заменить на что-нибудь другое, но точно сказать не могу. Может исходя из Id вычислить его координаты. Кроме этого ничего другого посоветовать не могу.